# Drawing a box around sub-strings of a document

Tags: java, html, parsing, substring, jsoup

I was hoping to get some help in how I should approach a program I have attempted to write a few times now.

I have a number of folders. In each folder, there is a HTML file, and a .txt file which contains text in the HTML file, stripped of all HTML tags.

As an example, a simplified HTML file may be

```html
<html><head></head><body><p>This is some <b>text</b></p><p>Please ignore me</p></body></html>
```

And within a .txt in the same folder, I have "This is some text".

From these two files, I would like to create a new file which is a HTML with a box drawn around "This is some text", like so :

[image: Image of the HTML file with a box crudely drawn around "This is some text"]

The obvious problem here is that the pretty-printed text files do not contain any mark-up, and so finding it within the HTML document is difficult.

My idea thus far has been :

-Save the .txt contents in a variable.
-Grab the HTML contents, strip of all HTML tags :

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

I'm unsure how to proceed from this point. I mean...I could try to add a div with a class surrounding the text, and then add a border style to this...but how do I find the sub-string in the HTML reliably, retaining all of the markup within the HTML ?

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this and I am just overthinking it, I would usually have a chat with a friend about this and solve it but everyone seems to be offline - so I come to you for guidance here.

Can anyone offer any feedback please? Thanks.

Comment: this may help: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

More information on [selectors](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) and [setting attribute values](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes)

```
private void test(){
    //replace with your stored variables
    String html = "<html><head></head><body><p>This is some <b>text</b></p><p>Please ignore me</p></body></html>";
    String txt = "This is some text";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    String query = "p:contains(" + txt + ")";
    Elements htmlTxt = doc.select(query); //selects all the paragraph elements with your target txt

    //Loop through each element and add a red border around it
    for(Element e : htmlTxt){
        System.out.println("e: " + e.toString());
        e.attr("style", "border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000; padding: 1em;");
    }
}
```